# Are physics engines accurate?

Tags: simulation, box2d, physics-engine

I'm trying to program a simulation for my physics paper. I saw Box2d as an option. My question is, are physics game engines like Box2d accurate for this kind of purposes?

Comment: I'd love to see this question reworded to more objectively ask how accurate physics engines like Box2D are, instead of whether they're accurate or not. Respondents then could provide more objective insights. In the meantime, ATV's answer seems spot on for answering the more subjective question of whether physics enhines are accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking game engines are usually aimed at making things *look* realistic though from experience I can say that many - sometimes undocumented - shortcuts are implemented in the engines to achieve real time simulation even on slow computing devices.

Your mileage may vary - but depending on your requirements I'd look into frameworks prioritizing **accuracy** over **speed of calculations**.